# Mail Subject decoding

Tags: python, unicode, decode, email-headers

Why does decoding the following fail

```
Subject: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?Begr=FC=DFungsschreibe?=n
```

while decoding the following works?

```
Subject: =?ISO-8859-1?Q?Begr=FC=DFungsschreiben?=
```

I read https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047 but could not find a note that there must be space after the end mark `?=`. That's the only difference between the two lines. In the first line (which is the failed one) there is the `n` directly after the end mark.

I used Python 2.7 for decoding.

I googled for a bug in Python, but could only found resolved issues.

Comment: Show *what* you try to decode it!

Comment: I showed **what** I want to decode. I did not show **how** (by intend). It should not matter in this context. This question is about specs.

Comment: I see, the confusion I guess comes from mentioning python. Do you actually ask if there might by a bug in some implementation? If it is yours than you should add it, if it is pythons why don't you **name the function you use**? **Which specs** do you refer to?

Comment: @Wolf thank you for your feedback. I updated the question. It is about RFC2047

Comment: Much clearer now (--1)

Comment: `I used Python 2.7 for decoding.` *What* of python did you use?

Comment: You are speaking of *space* in the working example, but I see no space in your code snippet. Has the line break (after the header line) the same effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RFC2047 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2047#section-5):

> an 'encoded-word' that appears in a header field defined as '*text' MUST be separated from any adjacent 'encoded-word' or 'text' by 'linear-white-space'.

The `Subject` header is defined as `*text` (and in any case the errata add the same restriction more generally to section 2).